# Can't get fd from tls.Conn

Tags: go, file-descriptor, epoll

Is there any way to get the file descriptor from a `tls.Conn`?

I'm trying to add tls to epoll. But I can't find fd in a tls.Conn.

Comment: It's not currently possible but has been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29257).

Comment: I found a solution. First, accept a net. Conn; Second, get its fd and add it to epoll; Third, upgrade net.Conn to tls.Conn.  Is this possible?

Comment: @InasaXia: If you have a solution, what are you asking is possible?

Comment: I add a method in tls.Conn.
func (c *Conn) UnderlyingConn() net.Conn {
    return c.conn
}

Answer (score 2):

```
 func FDFromTLSConn(conn tls.Conn) int {
    tcpConn := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(conn)).FieldByName("conn")
    fdVal := tcpConn.FieldByName("fd")
    pfdVal := reflect.Indirect(fdVal).FieldByName("pfd")

    return int(pfdVal.FieldByName("Sysfd").Int())
   }
```